# Null pointer error regarding graphics

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jpanel, paint

This is all inside my Board class, and it is supposed to be a class i can use to draw things to the screen with.

```
private JFrame frame;
private Pane pane;
private Image img;
private Graphics2D graphics;
private Dimension screenSize;
private Color backgroundColor;


public Board() {
    screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame = new JFrame("2D Game Arcade");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pane = new Pane();
    pane.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
    createMenus();
    frame.setContentPane(pane);
    backgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
    Dimension size = pane.getSize();
    img = pane.createImage(size.width, size.height);
    graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
    graphics.setColor(backgroundColor);
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
private class Pane extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics go) {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) go;
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

My error occurs here:

```
graphics = (Graphics2D) img.getGraphics();
```

as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is there some rule about using the graphics class I am unaware of?
I know that its abstract and cant be instantiated like such:

```
graphics = new Graphics2D();
```

without implementing all the abstract methods, which I do not want to do, but why is this a null pointer run time error?

Comment: A line number for the error would be good.

Comment: I realize it is null and i know what a null pointer exception is, but i want to know why img is null when I explicitly define it as 'img = pane.createImage(size.width, size.height);' @Jason

Comment: @Escap3faith When you checked the documentation for [`JPanel.createImage(int,int)`](http://bit.ly/1lcBoAz), what did you find?

Comment: @hexafraction The error line is provided after the block code, but its line 20 if you count the lines.

Comment: @JasonC "The return value may be null if the component is not displayable." I understand that, but why is img null? I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: @Escap3faith Then you did not "understand that". See my answer. Please don't stop after one click in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

A quick scan of all related documentation is all it takes to provide an answer.

Why is `createImage` returning `null`? From [`JPanel.createImage(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#createImage%28int,%20int%29):

> The return value may be `null` if the component is not displayable.

What does "not displayable" mean? The "see also" links may be a hint. From [`Component.isDisplayable()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable%28%29):

> A component is made displayable either when it is added to a displayable containment hierarchy or when its containment hierarchy is made displayable.

What does it mean for "its containment hierarchy [to be] made displayable"? Well the next sentence reads:

> A containment hierarchy is made displayable when its ancestor window is either packed or made visible.

So from the documentation, we can conclude that you should not call `createImage()` until after you have either packed or made visible the parent container.

Please do not use StackOverflow as a replacement for JDK documentation.

Comment: *"Please do not use StackOverflow as a replacement for JDK documentation."*  +10.